# splitting variable product code into letters and numbers

Tags: r, split

I have a product code  variable like:

```
Product Code
RMMI001,
RMMI001,
CMCM009,
ASCMOT064,
ASPMOA023,
CMCM009,
CMCM012,
CMCM001,
ASCMBW001,
RMMI001,
TMHO002,
TMSP001,
TMHO002,
TMDMST003
```

I need to split those and need these characters in another column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
# Sample product codes
ss <- c("RMMI001", "RMMI001", "CMCM009", "ASCMOT064", "ASPMOA023", "CMCM009", "CMCM012", "CMCM001", "ASCMBW001", "RMMI001", "TMHO002", "TMSP001", "TMHO002", "TMDMST003")

# Separate code and numbers and store in data.frame
read.csv(text = gsub("^([a-zA-Z]+)(\\d+)$", "\\1,\\2", ss), header = F)
#       V1 V2
#1    RMMI  1
#2    RMMI  1
#3    CMCM  9
#4  ASCMOT 64
#5  ASPMOA 23
#6    CMCM  9
#7    CMCM 12
#8    CMCM  1
#9  ASCMBW  1
#10   RMMI  1
#11   TMHO  2
#12   TMSP  1
#13   TMHO  2
#14 TMDMST  3
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try using `sub` here to remove all trailing numbers, leaving you with the character portion:

```
df <- data.frame(product_code=c("RMMI001", "RMMI001", "CMCM009"))
df$code <- sub("\\d*$", "", df$product_code)
df

  product_code code
1      RMMI001 RMMI
2      RMMI001 RMMI
3      CMCM009 CMCM
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tidyr::extract` as well, it works with dataframes only.

```
tidyr::extract(data.frame(x  =c("RMMI001", "CMCM009")),x, c("first", "second"), "([a-zA-Z]+)(\\d+)" )
```

**Output:**

```
#  first second
#1  RMMI    001
#2  CMCM    009
```

This will extract both the alphabets and numbers in separate columns, if you choose "([a-zA-Z]+)\d+" instead of "([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)". It will then extract only the first match represented as english words like below. Note the difference here is the capturing group represented by parenthesis.It is used here for capturing the match, in this case these are words and numbers into separate columns.

```
    tidyr::extract(data.frame(x  =c("RMMI001", "CMCM009")),x, c("first"), "([a-zA-Z]+)\\d+" )
   #   first
   # 1  RMMI
   # 2  CMCM
```

Comment: how can i use the above code for data = datafull , variable column name is product @PKumar

Comment: @prabhu prasad, `extract(datafull, product, "productnew", "([a-zA-Z]+)\\d+"),`

Comment: thanks a lot  ... productnew replaces the product , i dont want that to get replaced...instaed productnew want to be in additional column @PKumar

Comment: @prabhu prasad use a parameter , remove = F inside the function. It will keep your column.  extract(datafull, product, "productnew", "([a-zA-Z]+)\\d+", remove=F),

Comment: i have a data - variables are  product quantity, product code(1000 different types), date(day wise)...which model will suit to find prediction for  month wise, for each product code  @PKumar